# iron-form error response body

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am building a form using Polymer 1.0, using its `iron-form` element.

How can I get the error response body? The server is sending a JSON error back, and I can see it in the chrome inspector (network tab). But when my `iron-form-error` callback method is called, and I log it, the response JSON is nowhere to be found. I went through all the Object properties but nothing.

I also looked under `event.detail.request.response` but it is also null. Here is the code I'm using:

```
document.querySelector('#formPut').addEventListener('iron-form-error',function(e){
    console.log(e);
//  var json = $.parseJSON(e.detail.error.message);

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about code where you 'submit' the form. The async action on that should ref to the JSON response object.

Comment: Do you mean the server? Yes, it does reply with the `content-type` as `json/application`, and so I can see the response body (JSON) in the Chrome Inspector.

Comment: Whats firing "iron-form-error" ? Your response is generic json which must be parsed before u know if it was a success. Where is the parse code that fires your error?

Comment: The HTTP status code is 409, which fires the `iron-form-error`. There is JSON body in addition to this response code, which contains further details about the error. I need to display those errors. I cannot find the body JSON to parse.

Comment: Where is the async block (or JS promise) in which you get the actual JSON result fro the server? That 'result' object should contain the error object and the error string you are looking for . If the built in error from the form does not contain the 'result' you can get it elsewhere

Comment: There is only 1 result object I receive, which in this case is `e in function(e)`. This object has all header info of the response, but I cannot find the body. All the Async calls are handled by the Polymer library.

Comment: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/blob/master/iron-form.html  @208 ... listen for the response as well as the error...

Comment: These were among the first things I tried. But `event.detail` contains `error`, `request` and some other objects. None of these contain my response body. I even did `bower update` to check if it was fixed in recent versions. I wish there was a way to copy-paste the whole object I get back in chrome console.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+RobDodson/posts/eL1tjxgr1wV   try diff forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found my response body here...

```
e.detail.request.xhr.response
```

Comment: I'm really not liking their API for some of this stuff

Comment: So successful responses are in 'e.detail.response' and failures are in 'e.detail.request.xhr.response'. Gotta love the consistency lol.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the same thing under Polymer 1.0+, the status code can now be found under **event.detail.request.xhr.status**

```
_onError: function(event) {
    statusCode = event.detail.request.xhr.status;
}
```